Blender Addon - starting blender 4.2 through VS code stopped working
I am developing a blender addon and decided to use VS Code with the blender development and python extensions. While working with blender 4.1 I encountered no issues, but since the update(4.2) when I try opening a development server, I get the following error:
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/shutil.py", line 847, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/tmp/pip-target-zxossim0/lib/python/debugpy-1.8.5.dist-info' -> '/usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/debugpy-1.8.5.dist-info'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gras/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 105, in _run_wrapper
    status = _inner_run()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gras/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 96, in _inner_run
    return self.run(options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gras/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/gras/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 519, in run
    self._handle_target_dir(
  File "/home/gras/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 578, in _handle_target_dir
    shutil.move(os.path.join(lib_dir, item), target_item_dir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/shutil.py", line 863, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, copy_function=copy_function,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/shutil.py", line 600, in copytree
    return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/shutil.py", line 498, in _copytree
    os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=dirs_exist_ok)
  File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/debugpy-1.8.5.dist-info'

################################################################################
>   could not install debugpy
################################################################################


I have tried manually installing debugpy 1.8.5 from the original website .zip file. Both in my conda environment and globally. What am I missing out?
Thank you in advance!
